# Error java.lang.NullPointerException al cargar un JSON (Ooyala)

Tags: java, android, json, react-native, mediaplayer

Tengo un problema en mi aplicación de Android. Estoy trabajando en una aplicación multimedia que tiene un reproductor de vídeo y audio para reproducir contenido multimedia. El reproductor que utilizo es el de **Ooyala**. Este reproductor tiene la opción de ponerle una **skin personalizada**, que se configura a través de un **JSON**. En el archivo **JSON** se configura el aspecto que va a tener el player y después, desde la activity del player, se establece esta configuración.

Para poner en contexto, esta aplicación funcionaba con una arquitectura de **32 bits** y **react native 0.35.0**. Para poder actualizarla en Google Play Store, ahora en 2019, he tenido que actualizar la arquitectura de la aplicación a **64 bits**, migrar el proyecto a **Android X** y actualizar **react native** a la versión **0.59.9**.

Antes de la actualización el player funcionaba, sin embargo, tras todos los cambios realizados el player no es capaz de leer el archivo **skin.json** y crashea la aplicación al intentar reproducir cualquier vídeo/audio.

Utilizo las siguientes **SDK** y **librerías externas**:

- OoyalaSDK (versión 4.49.0_RC1)
- OoyalaSkinSDK
- react-native-0.59.9

Os adjunto el código de la activity del player de Ooyala (**OoyalaSkinPlayerActivity**) y la clase abstracta (**AbstractHookActivity**) de la que extiende.

> **AbstractHookActivity.java**

```java
package apuntmedia.es.lacolla.activity.modules.main.ooyala_player;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler;
import com.ooyala.android.OoyalaNotification;
import com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayer;
import com.ooyala.android.skin.OoyalaSkinLayoutController;
import com.ooyala.android.util.SDCardLogcatOoyalaEventsLogger;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

/**
 * This class asks permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. We need it for automation hooks
 * as we need to write into the SD card and automation will parse this file.
 */
public abstract class AbstractHookActivity extends Activity implements Observer, DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    String TAG = this.getClass().toString();
    protected OoyalaSkinLayoutController playerLayoutController;

    SDCardLogcatOoyalaEventsLogger log = new SDCardLogcatOoyalaEventsLogger();

    String embedCode;
    String pcode;
    String DOMAIN;
    protected final String APIKEY = "Use this for testing, don't keep your secret in the application";
    protected final String SECRET = "Use this for testing, don't keep your secret in the application";

    // An account ID, if you are using Concurrent Streams or Entitlements
    protected final String ACCOUNT_ID = "Account_ID";

    OoyalaPlayer player;

    boolean writePermission = false;
    boolean asked = false;

    // complete player setup after we asked for permission to write into external storage
    abstract void completePlayerSetup(final boolean asked);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else {
            writePermission= true;
            asked = true;
        }

        embedCode = getIntent().getExtras().getString("embed_code");;
        pcode = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pcode");;
        DOMAIN = getIntent().getExtras().getString("domain");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
            asked = true;
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                writePermission = true;
            }
            completePlayerSetup(asked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "Player Activity Stopped");
        if (null != player) {
            player.suspend();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d(TAG, "Player Activity Restarted");
        if (null != player) {
            player.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        playerLayoutController.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    /** Start DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler **/
    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    /** End DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler **/

    /** Start Activity methods for Skin **/
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (null != playerLayoutController) {
            playerLayoutController.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (null != playerLayoutController) {
            playerLayoutController.onResume( this, this );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (null != playerLayoutController) {
            playerLayoutController.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (null != playerLayoutController) {
            playerLayoutController.onDestroy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable arg0, Object argN) {

        final String arg1 = OoyalaNotification.getNameOrUnknown(argN);
        if (arg1 == OoyalaPlayer.TIME_CHANGED_NOTIFICATION_NAME) {
            return;
        }

        if (arg1 == OoyalaPlayer.ERROR_NOTIFICATION_NAME) {
            final String msg = "Error Event Received";
            if (null != player &&  null != player.getError()) {
                Log.e(TAG, msg, player.getError());
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, msg);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (arg1 == OoyalaSkinLayoutController.FULLSCREEN_CHANGED_NOTIFICATION_NAME) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fullscreen Notification received : " + arg1 + " - fullScreen: " + ((OoyalaNotification)argN).getData());
        }

        // Automation Hook: to write Notifications to a temporary file on the device/emulator
        String text="Notification Received: " + arg1 + " - state: " + player.getState();
        // Automation Hook: Write the event text along with event count to log file in sdcard if the log file exists
        log.writeToSdcardLog(text);
        Log.d(TAG, text);
    }
}
```

> **OoyalaSkinPlayerActivity.java**

```java
package apuntmedia.es.lacolla.activity.modules.main.ooyala_player;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayer;
import com.ooyala.android.PlayerDomain;
import com.ooyala.android.configuration.Options;
import com.ooyala.android.skin.BridgeEventHandler;
import com.ooyala.android.skin.OoyalaReactBridge;
import com.ooyala.android.skin.OoyalaSkinLayout;
import com.ooyala.android.skin.OoyalaSkinLayoutController;
import com.ooyala.android.skin.configuration.SkinOptions;

import org.json.JSONObject;


;import apuntmedia.es.lacolla.R;

/**
 * This activity illustrates how you can play basic playback video using the Skin SDK
 * you can also play Ooyala and VAST advertisements programmatically
 * through the SDK
 *
 */
public class OoyalaSkinPlayerActivity extends AbstractHookActivity {

    @Override
    void completePlayerSetup(boolean asked) {
        if(asked) {
            // Get the SkinLayout from our layout xml
            OoyalaSkinLayout skinLayout = findViewById(R.id.ooyalaSkin);
            PlayerDomain domain = new PlayerDomain(DOMAIN);
            // Create the OoyalaPlayer, with some built-in UI disabled
            Options options = new Options.Builder()
                    .setShowPromoImage(false)
                    .setShowNativeLearnMoreButton(false)
                    .setUseExoPlayer(true)
                    .build();
            player = new OoyalaPlayer(pcode, domain, options);

            //Create the SkinOptions, and setup React
            JSONObject overrides = createSkinOverrides();
            SkinOptions skinOptions = new SkinOptions.Builder().setSkinOverrides(overrides).build();
            playerLayoutController = new OoyalaSkinLayoutController(getApplication(), skinLayout, player, skinOptions);
            //Add observer to listen to fullscreen open and close events
            playerLayoutController.addObserver(this);
            player.addObserver(this);

            if (player.setEmbedCode(embedCode)) {
                player.play();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Asset Failure");
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SoLoader.init(this,false);//TODO: Cuando tenía el try/catch tenía que ponerle esto para que no saliera un error del Soloader.

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.player_skin_video_layout);

        completePlayerSetup(asked);
    }

    /**
     * Create skin overrides to show up in the skin.
     * Default commented. Uncomment to show changes to the start screen.
     * @return the overrides to apply to the skin.json in the assets folder
     */
    private JSONObject createSkinOverrides() {
        JSONObject overrides = new JSONObject();
        //JSONObject controlBarOverrides = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject showUpNextOverrides = new JSONObject();

        //JSONObject startScreenOverrides = new JSONObject();
        //JSONObject playIconStyleOverrides = new JSONObject();
        try {
            //controlBarOverrides.put("autoHide", false);
            showUpNextOverrides.put("showUpNext", false);
            //playIconStyleOverrides.put("color", "red");
            //startScreenOverrides.put("playButtonPosition", "bottomLeft");
            //startScreenOverrides.put("playIconStyle", playIconStyleOverrides);
            //overrides.put("startScreen", startScreenOverrides);

            //overrides.put("controlBar", controlBarOverrides);
            overrides.put("upNext", showUpNextOverrides);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception Thrown", e);
        }
        return overrides;
    }
}
```

Adjunto también el **build.gradle** app y project para comprobar, sobretodo, si se trata de alguna incompatibilidad con react native o algo similar. Omitiré algunas líneas del código por privacidad, pero estas líneas no tienen nada que ver con el problema.

> **build.gradle (Project)**

```java
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    vendorDir = new File(projectDir, '../vendor')
}
```

> **build.gradle (Module:app)**

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

def STRING = 'String'
def API_BASE = "API_BASE"
def API_APP_TOKEN = "API_APP_TOKEN"
def API_APP_ID = "API_APP_ID"
def API_VERSION = "API_VERSION"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "apuntmedia.es.lacolla"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 20
        versionName "1.3"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
            pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86/libjsc.so'
            exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }
}

task copyAssetsTask(type: Copy) {
    from new File(projectDir, '../../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/index.android.jsbundle')
    from new File(projectDir, '../../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/skin-config/skin.json')
    into new File(projectDir, './src/main/assets')
    println "Assets updated."
}
//tasks.copyAssetsTask.execute()
tasks.configure {copyAssetsTask}

task copySkinConfigTask(type: Copy) {
    from new File(projectDir, '../../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/skin-config')
    into new File(projectDir, './src/main/assets/skin-config')
    println "copySkinConfigTask updated."
}
//tasks.copySkinConfigTask.execute()
tasks.configure {copySkinConfigTask}

task copyFontsAssetsTask(type: Copy) {
    from new File(projectDir, '../../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/fonts')
    into new File(projectDir, './src/main/assets/fonts')
    println "font Assets updated."
}
//tasks.copyFontsAssetsTask.execute()
tasks.configure {copyFontsAssetsTask}

task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from new File(vendorDir, 'Ooyala/OoyalaSDK-Android/OoyalaSDK.aar')
    from new File(vendorDir, 'Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/OoyalaSkinSDK.aar')
    from new File(vendorDir, 'Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/react-native-0.59.9.aar')
    into new File(projectDir, './libs')
    println "Jars updated."

}
//tasks.copyTask.execute()
tasks.configure {copyTask}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'

    // Ooyala
    implementation files('libs/OoyalaSDK.aar')
    implementation files('libs/OoyalaSkinSDK.aar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation(name:'react-native', version:'0.59.9', ext:'aar')
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:0.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.6.0'//TODO: CAMBIADO DE 0.1.0 a 0.6.0
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'
    implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'

    // FCM
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.0.1'

    // Chromecast
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:16.0.1'
}

// Needed for Hugo
// https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Por último, os adjunto el error que me aparece en el logcat al intentar reproducir cualquier vídeo/audio en el reproductor de Ooyala dentro de la aplicación.

> **ERROR**

```
2019-11-22 08:26:31.221 18344-18344/apuntmedia.es.lacolla E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: apuntmedia.es.lacolla, PID: 18344
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{apuntmedia.es.lacolla/apuntmedia.es.lacolla.activity.modules.main.ooyala_player.OoyalaSkinPlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
        at com.ooyala.android.skin.util.JsonUtil.containsAtLeastOneNullValue(JsonUtil.java:46)
        at com.ooyala.android.skin.util.JsonUtil.removeNullsFromChildArray(JsonUtil.java:27)
        at com.ooyala.android.skin.configuration.SkinConfigManager.removeNullsFromPlaybackArray(SkinConfigManager.java:144)
        at com.ooyala.android.skin.OoyalaSkinLayoutController.initConfig(OoyalaSkinLayoutController.java:177)
        at com.ooyala.android.skin.OoyalaSkinLayoutController.initializeSkin(OoyalaSkinLayoutController.java:170)
        at com.ooyala.android.skin.OoyalaSkinLayoutController.<init>(OoyalaSkinLayoutController.java:162)
        at apuntmedia.es.lacolla.activity.modules.main.ooyala_player.OoyalaSkinPlayerActivity.completePlayerSetup(OoyalaSkinPlayerActivity.java:52)
        at apuntmedia.es.lacolla.activity.modules.main.ooyala_player.OoyalaSkinPlayerActivity.onCreate(OoyalaSkinPlayerActivity.java:85)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Es la primera vez que escribo, espero no haber cometido ningún fallo.

Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Comment: El mensaje de error dice: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()'`, pero en el código que has compartido no veo en qué parte intentas invocar `length()` sobre un JSON, debes mostrar el código sobre el que estás trabajando.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano. Gracias por responder. Desconozco el motivo, pero parece ser que el error del jsonArray.length viene de la clase JsonUtil.class:

private static boolean containsAtLeastOneNullValue(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
            if (jsonArray.isNull(i)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

Pero entiendo que el Logcat me indica que el error aparece ahí porque llamará a esa función para comprobar que el json no está vacío.

Comment: Yo no veo en ninguna parte del método compartido cómo se invoca a ese método. De todos modos es evidente que el JSON es nulo, tienes que verificar entonces qué pasa con tu JSON y por qué llega nulo. Puedes intentar mostrar el dato a partir del cual creas el JSON para ver si es convertible a JSON o no.

Comment: He comprobado que las tareas que intentan copiar el skin.json de una carpeta a otra utilizan una función que está obsoleta. Se trata de la función execute() en build.gradle (Module: app):

//tasks.copyAssetsTask.execute()
tasks.configure {copyAssetsTask}

Está comentada y he probado otras funciones pero no me copia los archivos de un directorio. Puede que lo que falle sea esto y me este creado un archivo skin.json vacío y por eso me lo detecta como null.

Comment: De hecho, ahora me he dado cuenta de que me aparece este aviso mientras hace el build de la aplicación:

The TaskInternal.execute() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. There are better ways to re-use task logic, see https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:reusing_task_logic.
 at build_73tbohclpnj476v2ernbojrn6.run(C:\Users\48605795X\Desktop\apunt_android_BUENA\app\build.gradle:73)
 (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

Comment: Pues debes corregir eso en tu Gradle, si la App no compila es imposible hacerla funcionar...

Comment: Sí que compila y funciona pero parece que estas tareas no las realiza. Por casualidad sabes porque método puedo sustituir el método execute()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he podido solucionar. Por si alguien ha tenido el mismo problema, se trataba de una nimiedad. Tan solo tenía un par de **rutas** mal y no cogía el archivo **JSON** del directorio correcto, por ello siempre llegaba vacío. Dejo el código bueno por aquí por si sirve a alguien!

Había que sustituir las tareas en:

> **build.gradle (app)**

```
task copyAssetsTask(type: Copy) {
    from new File(projectDir, '../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/index.android.jsbundle')
    from new File(projectDir, '../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/skin-config/skin.json')
    into new File(projectDir, './src/main/assets')
    println "Assets updated."
}
tasks.configure {copyAssetsTask}

task copySkinConfigTask(type: Copy) {
    from new File(projectDir, '../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/skin-config')
    into new File(projectDir, './src/main/assets/skin-config')
    println "copySkinConfigTask updated."
}
tasks.configure {copySkinConfigTask}

task copyFontsAssetsTask(type: Copy) {
    from new File(projectDir, '../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/fonts')
    into new File(projectDir, './src/main/assets/fonts')
    println "font Assets updated."
}
tasks.configure {copyFontsAssetsTask}

task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from new File(projectDir, '../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSDK-Android/OoyalaSDK.aar')
    from new File(projectDir, '../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/OoyalaSkinSDK.aar')
    from new File(projectDir, '../vendor/Ooyala/OoyalaSkinSDK-Android/react-native-0.59.9.aar')
    into new File(projectDir, './libs')
    doLast {
        println "Jars updated."
    }
}
tasks.configure {copyTask}
```